# To see which id's data drag and drop in multiconnect operation in jquery sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am doing sorting with jquery ui's sortable function. I have a problem. Anyone can help me?
for example, when I take a li from #sortable2 and move it to #sortable1, I want to assign the value 0 to the variable state and 1 when I move it from #sortable1 to #sortable2.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
  }).disableSelection();

  $("#sortable2").sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).children().each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).attr('data-position') != (index + 1)) {
          $(this).attr('data-position', (index + 1)).addClass('updated');
        }
      })
      saveNewPositions();
    }
  }).disableSelection();
});

function saveNewPositions() {
  var positions = [];
  $('.updated').each(function() {
    positions.push([$(this).attr('data-index'), $(this).attr('data-position'), $(this).attr('data-type')]);
    $(this).removeClass('updated');
  })

  $.ajax({
    url: SITE_URL + 'standart/islem.php?page=sortable',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {
      positions: positions,
      pageID: 1,
    },
    success: function(data) {
      data = data.split(":::", 2);
      var message = data[0],
        answer = data[1];
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li data-index="1" data-position="1">first row</li>
  <li data-index="2" data-position="2">second row</li>
</ul>
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li data-index="1" data-position="1">2. first row</li>
  <li data-index="2" data-position="2">2. second row</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function saveNewPositions() {
    var positions = [];
    $('.updated').each(function() {
      positions.push([$(this).attr('data-index'), $(this).attr('data-position'), $(this).attr('data-type')]);
      $(this).removeClass('updated');
    })

    $.ajax({
      url: SITE_URL + 'standart/islem.php?page=sortable',
      method: 'POST',
      dataType: 'text',
      data: {
        positions: positions,
        pageID: 1,
      },
      success: function(data) {
        data = data.split(":::", 2);
        var message = data[0],
          answer = data[1];
      }
    })
  }

  function resetList(el) {
    $("li", el).each(function(index, elem) {
      $(elem).attr("data-index", index + 1);
      $(elem).attr("data-position", index + 1);
    })
  }

  $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
  }).disableSelection();

  $("#sortable2").sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
      resetList(this);
    }
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li data-index="1" data-position="1">first row</li>
  <li data-index="2" data-position="2">second row</li>
</ul>
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li data-index="1" data-position="1">2. first row</li>
  <li data-index="2" data-position="2">2. second row</li>
</ul>
```

This is not really advisable. I would advise updating things when the Userhas completed all the changes they want to make.